# I need multiple users to rank list items and then display items by average rank

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-on-prem

Scenario: I have a list of items that need to be prioritized/ranked by multiple users. Each user needs to be able to view my list and enter a numerical ranking for each item and save.

There is a custom 'all item' view which needs to then display the list sorted by the AVERAGE rank by all users.

How can I accomplish this using a single column (ideally, but not a requirement) for ranking items?

Comment: is your list of users defined and limited? How many users will be doing prioritization?

Comment: there will be 20 people doing prioritization and my list of users is defined and limited.

Comment: Have you tried using Survey list with a question type Rating Scale (a matrix of choices or a Likert scale)?  Only limitation I can see is rating could up to 20

Comment: @SharePointer, i looked into that but the rating limits makes this an unfeasible solution. thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to:

1. Go to List Settings
2. Rating settings
3. Set Rating Settings to 'Yes'
4. Choose 'Star Ratings'
5. Create / modify views to sort by using a variety of columns, including 'Ratings (0-5)' or 'Number of Ratings.'

That's the easiest out-of-the-box way to do it, but let me know if it doesn't meet your requirements.

If you were asking for people to rank a list of items (i.e. a list of 10 items would have rankings up to 10) then you'd need to go another route. If you don't have a lot of users, you could create a column for each of their ratings. Otherwise, you're looking at a look up to hold the numbers in another list. That list is where you'd group by the item and then sort by average, etc, using the 'Totals' settings inside your view.

Comment: thanks for the reply. unfortunately, the star rating system doesn't meet my requirements. there will likely be a list of about 30 items, ranked 1-30, by about 20 different users. the lookup solution seems like a good one, but i don't understand how to set it up so that each user, when opening the list view, sees an empty 'ranking' column for each item, even after other users may have already entered their ranking. Edit: i am somewhat comfortable using SharePoint REST API if you think there may be a solution that could utilize that. I just can't think of what that could possibly be.

Comment: I don't like using a lot of columns for N responses, but how many users do you have? If it's not a lot, it could be easier to give them each their own column. This would make it easy for them to see if they'd filled theirs out yet, and you could use a calculated column to average them out.

Comment: I will have 30-50 different users, so giving each their own column could be problematic. Also, the users that will be ranking the list items may change, meaning the individual columns could potentially have to be updated quite a bit, making for alot of manual upkeep.